# gl_Position.z seemingly incorrect when used in fragment shader for animated meshes

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

While debugging my graphics engine I try to color everything at a certain distance in the direction of the camera. This works for static meshes, but animated meshes that use `animationMatrix` have small sections of fragments that either don't get colored, or change color when it shouldn't. As I see it `gl_Position.z` either doesn't gauge the depth correctly when I apply animations, or it can't be used as I intend it to.

[image: some fragments display the wrong color]

**Vertex Shader**

```
vec4 worldPosition = model * animationMatrix * vec4(coord3d, 1.0);
gl_Position = view_projection * worldPosition;
out float ClipSpacePosZ = gl_Position.z
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
in float ClipSpacePosZ;
if(ClipSpacePosZ > a){
    color.r = 1;
}
```

**Thought 1**

I had a similar problem with the fragment world position before, where I'd try to color by fragment world position and there would be similar artifacts. The solution was to divide the fragment position by the `w` component

```
out vec3 fragPos = vec3(worldPosition.x, worldPosition.y, worldPosition.z)/worldPosition.w;
```

I've tried similar ideas with ClipSpacePosZ. Maybe this is the solution that I'm missing some division by w, but I can't seem to find anything that works.

**Thought 2**

Could the depth for my fragments be incorrect, and they only seemingly display at the correct position.

**Thought 3**

`gl_Position` might do more things that I'm not aware of.

**Thought 4**

This only happens for animated meshes. There could be something wrong in my animation matrix. I don't understand why the position with `gl_Position` seemingly would be correct, but coloring by the depth wouldn't be.

Comment: Could you describe what would be the expected result be like? I think we are talking about the pinkish area at the bottom, right?

Comment: Ah yes, there is a line. Everything crossing that line should turn pinkish. Anything on the other side of that line should stay normal. As can be seen the model has areas that turn pink despite clearly being away from that line. The line is somewhat described in the fragment shader, where I set color.r = 1 if gl_Position.z > a (passed from vertex shader)

Comment: As far as I know, opengl camera looks at the negative Z direction. That means, the bigger the value, the closer that fragment is. Does the condition in the fragment shader consistent with it?

Comment: `gl_Position` is in  _clip space_, so the z coordinate does not mean what you think it does

Comment: Either, you want eye space `z` distance (which is `gl_Position.w` on a perspective projection), or some other space, but you have not explained that...

Comment: Could this be achieved by using the fragment shader's own `gl_fragCoord` by computing `gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w`? It all depends on what your question exactly is...